How to Schedule a Pod in different Node in GKE
I have cluster running in gke standard mode
Here is the details
PROD Env
GKE Standard Cluster running
with 2 Node Pool
and 9 Nodes
default-pool        1.28.3-gke.1286000    5 (1 - 2 per zone)    e2-standard-2    
xxxxxx-node-pool    1.28.11-gke.1019001   4 (2 per zone)    e2-highcpu-4 

Problem
is im using 2 PODs in different node it was running
but now when developer push code its not taking new changes code due to its running old-date tag and with latest it deploy im using CI/CD github action
how can i achive using automatically deployment in github action but that 2 pod should deploy only this is node-pool i.e., xxxxxxx-node-pool
here is my yaml file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: devops-test
 namespace: devops
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: devops-test
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: devops-test
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: devops-test
         image: us-south1-docker.pkg.dev/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:2024-07-29-1532
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080
         resources:
          requests: # Minimum amount of resources requested
             cpu: 1000m
             memory: 1024Mi
          limits: # Maximum amount of resources requested
             cpu: 2000m
             memory: 2048Mi
    #  nodeSelector:
    #    pod: engine         
     affinity:
      nodeAffinity:
       requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: pod
             operator: In
             values:
             - engine
       preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
       - weight: 1
         preference:
           matchExpressions:
           - key: pod
             operator: In
             values:
             - engine
       # - weight: 50
       #   preference:
       #     matchExpressions:
       #     - key: label-2
       #       operator: In
       #       values:
       #       - key-2              
---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
  name: devops-test
  namespace: devops
  annotations:
  labels:
    app: devops-test
 spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
   app: devops-test
  ports:
   - port: 8080
     targetPort: 8080
     protocol: TCP

And these are the 2 nodes which i want to deploy my 2 pods in these 2 nodes
gke-devops-prod-stan-devops-node-pool-8836938a-9gpw
gke-devops-prod-stan-devops-node-pool-bc9b2051-5zvg

i dont know very much of nodeAffinity or nodeSelector
I have off Autoscaling on both node-pool
I just want deployment to deploy automatically without any issues
This is Github Action deployment into PROD ENV
### Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) ###
    - name: Deploy to PROD Env (GKE)
      run: |
         gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
         gcloud container clusters get-credentials devpops-prod-standard --region us-central1 --project devops-production
         kubectl set image deployment devops-test devops-test=${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROD_PROJECT }}/${{ env.REPOSITORY }}/${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }} -n devops


Since the question is not about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be on-topic on [sf] or devops.

why its off-topic i have seen many people are post question related to pods, gke and kubernetes

As I said: it is not related to programming. Please take a look at the on-topic page. An on-topic question must be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

From what I understand you only want the pods to be scheduled on these nodes:
gke-devops-prod-stan-devops-node-pool-8836938a-9gpw
gke-devops-prod-stan-devops-node-pool-bc9b2051-5zvg
The yaml has pod affinity for:
matchExpressions:
- key: pod
operator: In
values:
- engine
Please create nodepool with labels (key: pod, value: engine) or if GKE allows editing, please add labels to existing nodepool.
This should hopefully resolve issue.

Issue didnt solve because when developer commit the new code or changes and Pod is not taking its showing pending when i describe the pod its say
0/9 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory, 7 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/9 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 7 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp        97s                cluster-autoscaler       pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added):
